# Get combined grouped counts from 2 tables

Tags: psql

I'd like to combine counts of a variable (injections) grouped by week for two separate tables (`myo` and `cbp`). I can do this easily for each table individually

`SELECT EXTRACT (week from cbp_date) as week, count(*) FROM cbp where EXTRACT (year from cbp_date) = '2018' and cbp_injected_by = 'ABC' group by week order by week asc`

and

`SELECT EXTRACT (week from myo_date) as week, count(*) FROM myo where EXTRACT (year from myo_date) = '2018' and myo_injected_by = 'ABC' group by week order by week asc`

How can I combine these queries with a `UNION` and grouping by `week`?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think a join might actually make more sense here.  The query below reports each week with the respective counts from both tables alongside each other.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT (WEEK FROM cbp_date) AS week,
    COUNT(*) AS cbp_cnt
    FROM cbp
    WHERE EXTRACT (year from cbp_date) = '2018' AND cbp_injected_by = 'ABC'
    GROUP BY week
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT (WEEK FROM myo_date) AS week,
    COUNT(*) AS myo_cnt
    FROM myo
    WHERE EXTRACT (year from myo_date) = '2018' AND myo_injected_by = 'ABC'
    GROUP BY week
)

SELECT
    t1.week,
    t1.cbp_cnt,
    t2.myo_cnt
FROM cte1 t1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.week = t2.week;
```

I assume here that both tables, in particular the `cbp` table, have data for all weeks of 2018, or if they don't that you don't mind not reporting missing weeks.  To get the exact output you want you might need to join with a calendar table, but hopefully this is still a useful suggestion.

**Edit:** If, for some reason, your version Postgres does not support CTE, then you may just join two subqueries, e.g.

```
SELECT
    t1.week,
    t1.cbp_cnt,
    t2.myo_cnt
FROM
(
    -- cte1
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    -- cte2
) t2
    ON t1.week = t2.week;
```

Comment: That solution would definitely work however there seems to be a syntax issue with 'WITH'  (I'm using version 8.4 and I think I have had issues with WITH in the past)

Comment: @moadeep If your version of Postgres does not support CTE, then you may just inline them as subqueries.